# Symlink to the latest version formula directory in Homebrew

Tags: macos, homebrew

I'm kinda just starting with OS X and Homebrew, yet I find it very useful. However I have one problem: is there a way to make Homebrew automatically create a symlink to the directory of the latest version of a formula? For example, after installing gradle we have

```
/usr/local/Cellar/gradle/1.6
```

and it would be very handy (for external configurations) to have also something like

```
/usr/local/Cellar/gradle/current
```

(helps with avoiding reconfiguration after formula was updated).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Current Homebrew (4.x)  on Apple Silicon machines stores symlinks to the latest versions in `/opt/homebrew/opt/`:

```
➜ ls -l /opt/homebrew/opt/ | head -n5
total 0
lrwxr-xr-x  1 werner  admin  22 Nov  8  2021 0mq -> ../Cellar/zeromq/4.3.4
lrwxr-xr-x  1 werner  admin  19 Oct 24 14:53 ack -> ../Cellar/ack/3.6.0
lrwxr-xr-x  1 werner  admin  31 Oct 24 14:37 adwaita-icon-theme -> ../Cellar/adwaita-icon-theme/43
lrwxr-xr-x  1 werner  admin  21 Nov  8  2021 aften -> ../Cellar/aften/0.0.8
```

This used to be in `/usr/local/var/homebrew/linked/` for older Homebrew versions.

Homebrew on x64 machines, using Rosetta 2, writes to `/usr/local/opt` instead.

Comment: thanks for the quick update! I'll delete my comment (and this one, in a bit)

Comment: I'm on brew 4.0.17 on macOS (x86), and for me these links are in `/usr/local/opt`.

Comment: @JohanWalles You are running an x86 installation. Homebrew used to place those files in `/usr/local` but does no longer do this for Apple Silicon, instead writing to its own directory in `/opt`.

Answer (score 2):

The current accepted answer is outdated. For me:

```
$ brew --version
Homebrew 1.1.9
```

The current formula directories are symlinked in:

`/usr/local/var/homebrew/linked/`

Comment: I fixed my answer. You could have also left me a comment – or even proposed your edit – and I would have updated it. This way I didn't even notice it was wrong or outdated.